# difference between snmpwalk and check_snmp_int

Tags: monitoring, nagios, snmp, graph

what is the difference between check_snmp_int and snmpwalk command to get the ifInOctects 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10
my check_snmp_int  gives wrong values for bandwith monitoring ,  ifInOctects  and ifOutoctect gives values that vary , should they be equal ?
Can i use the snmpwalk to get the bandwiith of a switch instead of check_snmp_int ?
if more details are needed ,i can provide them 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

> check_snmp_int gives wrong values for bandwith monitoring...

By default, `check_snmp_int` do the average between the datas retrieved by snmp. So your results can differ.

> ifInOctects and ifOutoctect gives values that vary , should they be equal ?

No, it's two différents values, one for the IN and the other for the OUT traffic of your interface.

> Can i use the snmpwalk to get the bandwiith of a switch instead of check_snmp_int

`ifInOctects` and `ifOutoctect` store only the number of octets transmitted on the interface. There is not notion of time in those values. So `snmpwalk` will only retrieve this number of octets, if you don't want to use check_snmp_int 
to have the average of your traffic, you will must calculate yourself the average in fonction of the a intervall of time.

check_snmp_int doses that, look at the help of the check, it explains how the plugin works. [Help of check_snmp_int](http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_int.html)

Comment: what i meant was that should the value of inOctet and OutOctect be equal to the value of check_snmp_int to get the bandwith ( PortIn , and PortOut )
And yes i would have liked using the check_snmp_int but it doesnt seem to work since it gives steady values , so to calculate the bandwith , i can instead create my own script and calculate the values based on the snmpwalk or snmpget ?? did i get you correctly ?

Comment: The bandwith calculated with `snmp_net_int` is not in real time. The measurement depends of the intervall between two checks. If you do a check every 5 minutes, you will an average of your bandwith on 5 minutes. So if you have a burst in this intervall it will be averaged during these 5 minutes